# How to perform database queries in GHCi in Yesod Application

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent, ghci

How to, for example, insert a new User into a database using Yesod application's models? Or is there a better way?

I am dealing with scaffolded application. Now I created `App` instance and dont know how to perform requests using it.

```
:i Extra
data Extra
  = Extra {extraCopyright :: Data.Text.Internal.Text,
           extraAnalytics :: Maybe Data.Text.Internal.Text}
        -- Defined in `Settings

let e = Extra "asdf" Nothing
let c = AppConfig {appEnv = Development, appPort = 3000, appRoot = "/", appHost = "localhost", appExtra = e}
f <- makeFoundation c
:t f
f :: App

:i App
data App
  = App {settings :: AppConfig DefaultEnv Extra,
         getStatic :: Yesod.Static.Static,
         connPool :: persistent-1.2.3.0:Database.Persist.Class.PersistConfig.PersistConfigPool
                       PersistConf,
         httpManager :: http-client-0.2.0.1:Network.HTTP.Client.Types.Manager,
         persistConfig :: PersistConf,
         appLogger :: Yesod.Core.Types.Logger}
        -- Defined in `Foundation'
```

What next?

Comment: What is the first thing you tried?

Comment: It looks like I need create foundation (which is `App` by default) and perform queries with it somehow.

Comment: I am stuck on creating `AppConfig` instnance for creating `App` with `makeFoundation` defined in `Foundation` module (which is default scaffolded).

Comment: Why don't you update your question w/ what you are stuck on. Being more specific will help.

Comment: Do you need the Yesod App or do you just want to know how to interact with Persistent in ghci?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to do Persistent queries in ghci you can do this without creating a Yesod application.  Unfortunately doing this is differs quite a bit depending on the specific back end you want to use.

For SQLite:

```
> import Database.Persist.Sqlite
> import Model
> pool <- createSqlitePool "yesod-test.sqlite3" 2
> runSqlite "yesod-test.sqlite3" (runMigration migrateAll)
> userId <- runSqlite "yesod-test.sqlite3" (insert (User "foo@bar.com" Nothing))
```

For Postgresql:

```
-- In Shell: $ createdb yesod-test
> import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple
> con <- connectPostgreSQL  "dbname=yesod-test"
> import Database.Persist.Postgresql
> pcon <- openSimpleConn con
> import Model
> runSqlPersistM (runMigration migrateAll) pcon
> userId <- runSqlPersistM (insert (User "foo@bar.com" Nothing)) pcon
> Just user <- runSqlPersistM (get userId) pcon
> userIdent user
```

Answer (score 4):

The scaffolding provides (at least with yesod-bin 1.4.5) a function `db` in `Application.hs` which you can use:

```
$ cabal repl
...
*Application> db $ insert $ User "foo@bar.com" Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the accepted answer is pretty old. Here is an update for running persistent queries in IO with the postgresql backend.

```
import Control.Monad.Reader (ReaderT)
import Control.Monad.Logger (LoggingT, runStdoutLoggingT)
import Database.Persist.Sql (SqlBackend, runSqlConn)
import Database.Persist.Postgresql (withPostgresqlConn)

runDBIO :: ReaderT SqlBackend (LoggingT IO) a -> IO a
runDBIO = runStdoutLoggingT . withPostgresqlConn "dbname=test-db" . runSqlConn
```