# How to use logFunc with openSimpleConn in Persistent Postgresql module?

Tags: postgresql, haskell, ghci

I am learning Yesod and was looking for postgresql usage examples in ghci when I ran into this

[How to perform database queries in GHCi in Yesod Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968016/how-to-perform-database-queries-in-ghci-in-yesod-application/20977526#20977526)

```
pcon <- openSimpleConn con
```

The package has changed since this answer was given and now openSimpleConn requires a LogFunc in addition to the Connection string. Reading the docs for [openSimpleConn](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-postgresql-2.0.1/docs/Database-Persist-Postgresql.html) and [LogFunc](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.0.1.1/docs/Database-Persist-Sql.html#t:LogFunc) does not yield any examples regarding where to get a LogFunc or how to use one (I am still new to Haskell)

Assuming it wants some kind of logging function, I tried doing

```
pcon <- openSimpleConn runStdoutLoggingT con
```

But this was met with

```
<interactive>:22:9: Not in scope: ‘runStdoutLoggingT’
```

At which point I decided I needed some help.

So, my questions are, what is a LogFunc and what is the proper way to get and use one?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest implementation you can use it `\_ _ _ _ -> return ()`, i.e., ignore all arguments and do nothing. For more details on what's going on, check out the [monad-logger package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-logger-0.3.7.2/docs/Control-Monad-Logger.html).